# Getting error - "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized." while requesting file with Google Drive API

Tags: google-drive-api, http-headers, httprequest, http-status-code-401

While downloading files from Google Drive, specifically with extensions .docx, .doc, or .pdf, we are now using the "WebContentLink" property through filePicker API as per the recent modification in the Google Drive API to get the file. (Previously, we were using downloadUrl file property to download the file through filePicker API).

However, we are getting this unwanted exception **"401 - Unauthorized access**" while authorizing download requests to the API using HttpWebRequest by passing header using bearer token.

**Google Drive API version - v2**

Used - File Picker API to get the file data, i.e. file ID, webContentLink, alternateLink

Here's the piece of code where we have implemented the logic

```
//fileurl - webcontentlink of the file (previously, we used downloadUrl)
//accessToken - client's accessToken 
//filepath - location to store the downloaded file
```

```
public void downloadGdriveFileThroughWebRequest(string fileurl, string filepath, string accessToken)
        {
            HttpWebRequest rq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(fileurl);
            rq.Method = "GET";
            rq.PreAuthenticate = true;
            rq.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
            try { 
            HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)rq.GetResponse();
            using (Stream output = File.OpenWrite(filepath))
            {
                using (Stream s = resp.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = s.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        output.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
            }
            }

            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                using (var stream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    reader.ReadLine();
                    Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd());
                }
            }
        }
```

If we do not pass headers, we are able to download the file but not able to read and write its data so that's of no use!

Is there any alternate solution to download the requested Google Drive file through API requests with HTTP headers?

NOTE - Here's the recent modification to the Google Drive and Picker APIs - https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-development/upcoming-changes-to-the-google-drive-api-and-google-picker-api
and we have already made the changes.

Comment: does the user have access to that file?

Comment: yes @DaImTo, we are using the user's access token to download the file.

Comment: Got a solution from google drive support- 

For downloading a file using the Drive API V2 by an HTTP request and setting the access token in the header, you need to request it to this url:

https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/{fileId}?alt=media

Comment: @RuchiYevle did that work then? If so could you please formalise the comment in an answer so that everyone encountering that issue finds the solution easily?

Comment: @MateoRandwolf, yep. That worked.
As Google Drive API now no longer supports the functionality to download the file using "downloadURL"  using access token, we will have to use the URL

googleapis.com/drive/v2/files{fileId}?alt=media instead.
This worked for me and also, it is the intended behaviour as mentioned in their issue tracker

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

*This solution is brought to you by @RuchiYevle , the original poster who in the comments posted what worked for him. Therefore, this will be posted as a community wiki.*

As Google Drive API now **no longer supports the functionality to download files using** `downloadURL` using access token, we will have to use the URL `googleapis.com/drive/v2/files{fileId}?alt=media` instead.

*This worked for me and also, it is the intended behaviour as mentioned in their issue tracker.*